# Which module loads the requested library?

Tags: ssh, libraries, kernel-module

I'm using a remote machine from the terminal (ssh protocol). I don't have sudo powers on that.

I need to run a software that complains about a missing library:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmpi_usempif08.so.40: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I know that this library is loaded by some module, like:

```
module load ABC
```

but I don't know what's the right module.

How do I discover which module I should load in order to have a specific library?

Thank you!

Comment: "I know that this library is loaded by some module" - First time hear that a **kernel module** loads a **library**. Are you sure about that?

Comment: Uhm... Nope! :)

I'm 10000% sure that the my software works only if I load the "right" modules, otherwise I get those error due to missing libraries.

Comment: Depending on your distribution you have to install `libopenmpi40` or alike.